# Adjust windows sensitivity by pure numeric value? (So I can adjust settings to compensate for a new mouse)

Tags: windows, mouse

I'm using an 800dpi, 500mhz mouse right now, but I'm getting a new one since this one is acting all silly. The mouse I want to get is 3600dpi. From what I know, I should be able to get my sensitivity in my games (e.g CSGO) and simply adjust them to compensate for the DPI difference. HOWEVER, in windows, all I see is this

[image]

And so I'm not sure how I'd adjust my new mouses settings to compensate for the difference in DPI. Is there a way that I can change the sensitivity based on a numeric value or am I totally wrong about the way this all works?

Answer (score 0):

since you got such a mouse, i suggest you use the manufacturers drivers for that for more flexible configuration. however, cant help with the software or its name cause i have no idea what mouse you have.

for a more experienced users you could check out the http://translate.google.pl/translate?sl=ja&tl=en&u=07.net%2Fmouse%2F which has posted here earlier, itll give you a good idea of how to fix it

however I DO NOT SUGGEST THAT FOR A NORMAL USER, as its the registry modifications which require more than common knowledge of windows.

Comment: i'll be going from a Tt esports Saphira to a cheaper but properly working GAMDIAS Demeter GMS5010.

Answer (score 0):

Some games, I'm not sure if CS:GO is one of them, will overwrite you windows mouse sensitivity.

I'd suggest turning your windows sensitivity to max or min then open your game and check to see if you feel the difference.

Comment: i'm talking about the windows desktop cursor, the game was just a comparison as to how i can directly change the sensitivity of the mouse by a numeric value to get the exact same feel despite a dpi change